# What to do when there are different input arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript right now, quite a task being new to both the syntax and DOM manipulation.

Right now I'm not really using jQuery(or any other library). I've used it before but not interested at the moment since I want to get the hang of it then move to a library. I'm looking for plain JavaScript examples that do not involve libraries.

```
<form name="carritoDeCompras" action=""> 
 <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="17%">Nombre de Articulo </td>
    <td width="22%">Precio</td>
    <td width="51%"> Cantidades</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Desktop</td>
    <td><input name="price[]" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="1900.00" id="1 "/></td>
    <td><input name="cantidad[]" type="text" value="4" id="1 cantidad" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monitor</td>
    <td><input name="price[]" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="322.00" id="2" /></td>
    <td><input name="cantidad[]" type="text" value="2" id="2 cantidad" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Disco Duro</td>
    <td><input name="price[]" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="244.33" id="3"/></td>
    <td><input name="cantidad[]" type="text" value="10" id="3 cantidad" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mouse</td>
    <td><input name="price[]" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="100.21" id="4"/></td>
    <td><input name="cantidad[]" type="text" value="100" id="4 cantidad" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My goal is to separate both price and quantity (cantidad) and sum them with an "update price" button. It has left me in doubt on how to grab those "price[]" "cantidad[]" inputs and keep them separated, so I can create a loop and well do the math.

Sorry for the spanish/english mix, gets in the way,

Comment: +1 for wanting to learn without a library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `document.getElementsByName`

```
var prices = document.getElementsByName("price[]");
var quantities = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
```

Documentation for [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByName) (Firefox).

And in case you need help with the iteration:

```
var totalPrice    = 0,
    totalQuantity = 0,
    i;

i = prices.length;
while ( i-- ) { totalPrice    += +prices[i]     || 0; }

i = quantities.length;
while ( i-- ) { totalQuantity += +quantities[i] || 0; }
```

The `+` in `+prices[i]` casts the value to an integer.  The `|| 0` is to make sure that only numbers are returned.  If `prices[i]` is a string like "asdf", `+"asdf"` evaluate to `NaN` which means that `totalPrice += NaN` would also be `NaN`.  However, `NaN || 0` evaluates to `0`, so you can avoid this problem.

Comment: Gah, I was so close to the answer, but since I've been looking at the problem for an hour already it was already getting frustrating =/. Thanks a lot, you really got me with the "+= +prices[i]     || 0;" left me with wondering. 

I can handle the iteration now, since the item's price has to match the quantity's id (and item's id so I can multiply the item). 

One last question, why is there "object.text (from an example), or object.data, object.innerHTML. object.value" and are different from Node's value?

Comment: Where are you getting `object` from?  `value` will be defined for `form` elements like `input`, `select` and `textarea`.  `innerHTML` is typically defined on most elements and is a string representation of everything inside of that tag.  Here's a pretty good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element

Answer (score 2):

You can use a method named `getElementsByName()`. Example:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    total += inputs[i].value - 0; // the - 0 is there to make sure the value is converted to a number
}
```

The `total` variable now contains the total amount.

[Documentation on `getElementsByName()` at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp).

Comment: You're missing you're incrementor

Comment: So I was, I wrote it in a hurry :)